# How can I extract a long list of tarballs via STDIN?

Tags: bash, tar

I'm copying bunch of .tar backups of user home directories to a new server and have the tarballs already copied from the old server to the new server.

For Example;

```
[root@example.com /home]# ls /home |grep tar
returns:
user1.tar
user2.tar
user3.tar
[etc]
```

But making things a little trickier, the tarballs were created from the root directory on the original server so a default extraction has 'home' in the default path e.g.;

```
[root@example.com /home]# tar -xvf user1.tar
```

extracts to a new home directory relative to where your running the command and places the extracted files at the path

```
/home/home/user1
```

The closest I believe I have come to what's required (with a few different variations);

```
[root@example.com /]# ls /home |grep tar |tar -xvf -
```

returns;

```
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

Now I realize there's a lot of workarounds for each of the different pieces, but if I'm going to grow up to be a super-cool sysadmin like my friends, I should probably know super-cool tricks like this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tar` expects a tar file on stdin, not a list of filenames.

Process each file separately:

```
ls *.tar | xargs -n 1 tar xvf
```

or

```
for file in *.tar; do tar xvf $file; done
```

Comment: `ls *.tar` can be `echo *.tar`; there's no need to invoke the `ls` command, which in this case will simply print its arguments. (Unless you happen to have one or more directories with names matching `*.tar`.) And I'm sure you don't want the `z` option in that second command.